# setOnTouchListener() is giving me an error

Tags: android, eclipse

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOUR TEXT", 5000).show();
  }
});
```

Eclipse states the following:

> The method setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener) in the type View
>   is not applicable for the arguments (new OnTouchListener(){})

Imports:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.Toast;
```

Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: It must be your imports.  Please show them (and the class declaration line).  Try `new View.OnTouchListener()`  Does that fix it?

Comment: I would also do a project clean and rebuild

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOUR TEXT", 5000).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions:

1. Add `import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;` to the beginning of your class
2. Replace `button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()` with `button.setOnTouchListener(new ViewOnTouchListener()` as Chiral Code suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Check your code: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html
You should use method onTouch.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
public void onClick(View v)
  {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOUR TEXT", 5000).show();
  }
```

is not valid for an onTouchListener. That is why you are getting the error, you should be using

```
@Override
public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
      {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOUR TEXT", 5000).show();
      }
```

instead if you really want an onTouchListener, although I highly suggest Chiral Code's suggestion of using an onClickListener

Answer (score 1):

and when u use new OnTouchListener() u need to override on onTouch not onClick or change it to
   plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

```
 @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOUR TEXT", 5000).show();

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are putting an ontouchlistener with an onclick listener thats your mistake.

```
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOUR TEXT", 5000).show();
    return false;
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and I had to do 'fix project setup' which I found after clicking the quick fixes option. I then added a .jar file and it was all good.

Comment: Can you please add more details to your answer?