# android button switch text with imageButton

Tags: android, button

I have button1 with text "ohio", button2 with text "alaska", and ImageButton with arrow as background. I want to switch text Button1 to Button2 and vice versa when ImageButton clicked, how do I achieve this? or is there any reference in github that I can try?

Comment: its easy just handle imagebutton click and switch text of each by button.settext("YOUR_TEXT");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I understand you make imageButton as toggle when you click on it you change text here is the code

```
 boolean clicked = false;
String button1text = "ohio";
String button2text = "alaska";

ImageButton mImageButton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonID);
Button mImageButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonID);
Button mImageButton2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonID2);

mImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
mImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
mImageButton2.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageButtonID:
              if(clicked){
               clicked = false;
               mImageButton.setText(button1text);
               mImageButton2.setText(button2text );
               }else{
                mImageButton.setText(button2text);
                mImageButton2.setText(button1text );
                clicked = true;
                 }
             break;
              }
}
```

Comment: yes...this is what I need, thanks

Comment: and what if instead of button, use EditText? 
because if I change it to EditText I got java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: just change button to EditText and it will work fine check settext http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence, android.widget.TextView.BufferType)

Comment: it works, but I have to click twice to get it work...I resolve it with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793152/setontouchlistener-is-giving-me-an-error), change onClick with onTouch

Answer (score 0):

You can do this setting a ID for button1 and other for button2 in your XML
and in your activity you can do something like:

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ID_IMAGE_BUTTON));
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button button1 = (Button) findById(R.id.ID_BUTTON1);
        String textButton1 = button1.getText().toString;

        Button button2 = (Button) findById(R.id.ID_BUTTON2);
        String textButton2 = button2.getText().toString;

        button1.setText(textButton2);
        button2.setText(textButton1);
    }
});
```

Comment: it works but only switch once...I want every time I click ImageButton they switch text....